# PuTTy command line ~# versus ~$

Tags: ssh, putty

I'm a beginner at learning to use the Raspberry Pi, and I was wondering what the difference between `pi@raspberry:~#` and `pi@raspberry:~$` are? I'm using PuTTy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#` for refers to root and `$` refers to a regular user.

You can use either, but if you are running lots of commands that require root access logging in using `pi@raspberry:~#` is probably more useful than using `pi@raspberry:~$`, just because it saves adding `sudo` to the start of commands that require root access.

Comment: Thanks mate 
Just as a follow up, would that involve me logging in as "root" rather than "pi" when using Putty?

Comment: I think logging in as `pi` will work, if it doesn't I guess you would have to log in as `root`.

Comment: It is safer to login as the Pi user and switch to the root user (sudo su). This will allow you to disable root logins via SSH.